# Web scraping google flight prices

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn to use the python library BeautifulSoup, I would like to, for example, scrape a price of a flight on Google Flights.
So I connected to Google Flights, for example at [this link](https://www.google.com/flights?hl=it#flt=/m/07_pf./m/05qtj.2019-04-27;c:EUR;e:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o), and I want to get the cheapest flight price.

So I would get the value inside the div with this class "gws-flights-results__itinerary-price" (as in the figure).

[image: figure example]

Here is the simple code I wrote:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=it#flt=/m/07_pf./m/05qtj.2019-04-27;c:EUR;e:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'gws-flights-results__itinerary-price'})
```

But the resulting div has class `NoneType`.

I also try with

```
find_all('div')
```

but within all the div I found in this way, there was not the div I was interested in.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like javascript needs to run so use a method like selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=it#flt=/m/07_pf./m/05qtj.2019-04-27;c:EUR;e:1;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price').text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did not consider Selenium. It works, thanks.

Comment: I would like to ask how can I handle now since class name become decoded value

Answer (score 2):

Its great that you are learning web scraping! The reason you are getting NoneType as a result is because the website that you are scraping loads content dynamically. When requests library fetches the url it only contains javascript. and the div with this class "gws-flights-results__itinerary-price" isn't rendered yet! So it won't be possible by the scraping approach you are using to scrape this website.

*However you can use other methods such as fetching the page using tools such as selenium or splash to render the javascript and then parse the content.*

Comment: Hi Khan, thanks for your comment. I didn't know about splash. I will look forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is a great tool for extracting part of HTML or XML, but here it looks like you only need to get the url to another GET-request for a JSON object.

(I am not by a computer now, can update with an example tomorrow.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I resolved my question with the code posted by QHarr.Thanks again.