# PHP Scraper to get flight prices from google flights

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the cheapest flight price from google flights, let's say this link https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=LAX.LAS.2020-06-07*LAS.LAX.2020-06-11;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f

```
require 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';
$link = 'https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=LAX.LAS.2020-06-07*LAS.LAX.2020-06-11;c:USD;e:1;sd:1;t:f';
$html = file_get_html($link);

$title = $html->find('title', 0);
$price = $html->find('.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price');

echo $title->plaintext."<br>\n";
if ($price) {
    echo $price[0]->plaintext."<br>\n";
}
```

But I'm not getting any result for the price. I've read somewhere that there needs to be javascript run since the DOM on google flights is being generated by javascript. But I'm not sure how to do this with PHP. I welcome any help, or some alternative or better approach to scrape data from google flights using php or javascript.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to do this with PHP"...because you can't. JavaScript runs in a browser environment. PHP is not a browser and therefore cannot execute the Javascript.

Comment: I suggest trying to find a flight API, instead of trying to scrape data from complex websites. I would imagine there are plenty available if you google it, maybe even some you can use for free or for a small fee. Getting the data in machine-readable format will be easier and more reliable.

Comment: I have seen a post where it's possible to do using selenium web driver with python.
Just looking for an alternative using PHP or Javascript?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407247/web-scraping-google-flight-prices

Comment: Well yes that might work. you can power selenium using PHP just the same. Did you try just googling "selenium php" ?? You'll find, among other similar links: https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/ and https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver

Comment: Thanks for this. I need some help to install and run this on a shared hosting instead of localhost. Is it possible? If yes, how do I need to get it working?

Comment: I'm not experienced with selenium but again a simple Google search reveals some interesting things including this: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-install-Selenium-server-on-my-hosting-account-If-not-then-is-there-any-alternative-to-do-that . So I suspect you need a different setup really. P.s. please do try doing some simple research if you can.

Comment: I have looked into these already but I'm not sure if that was succeeded or not. I'm just looking for some experienced/successful implementation under my constraints. The quora link states that we can use some hosted service like browser stack etc. But I'm not sure if it will worth the effort.

"So I suspect you need a different setup really" Do you mean I'd need to get on with a dedicated server/VPS etc?

Comment: I think it's more likely to be possible like that yes. Because with shared hosting you are usually very restricted about what you can install.