# How to handle dynamic html tag class name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-tag-details

It seems like they updated page after pandemic. It doesn't have class name like 'gws-flights-results__itinerary-price' like this post [web scrapping google flight prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407247/web-scraping-google-flight-prices?rq=2). How could we locate flight info if I want to use selenium or beautiful soap to scrap occationally.
I used hard code class name, but this seems not scalable and may not work once flight airports are changed. Should I use other ways?

```
departure_airpot = tag.find('div',class_="ZHa2lc tdMWuf y52p7d").get_text()
    arrival_airport =tag.find('div',class_="FY5t7d tdMWuf y52p7d").get_text()
    departure_time = tag.find('div',class_="b0EVyb YMlIz y52p7d").get_text()
    arrival_time = tag.find('div',class_="b0EVyb YMlIz y52p7d").get_text()
    carrier = tag.find('div',class_="MX5RWe sSHqwe y52p7d").get_text()
    flight_num = tag.find('div',class_="Xsgmwe sI2Nye").get_text()
    flight_price= bs.find('div',class_="YMlIz FpEdX jLMuyc").get_text()
```

thanks a lot.

[image: google flight search results]

Comment: If the tag is in the same _place_ on the page, relative to the surrounding tags, then searching for the tag by its xpath might be a good solution.